# How to hide/minimum Firefox Developer Tool without close it?

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

Because Open/Close it loss all requests in tab Network, so how to hide/minimum Firefox Developer Tool without close it?

Similar to Firebug.
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is currently (as of Firefox 52.0.2) no option to minimize the DevTools. Until Firefox 40 there was one, though it [got removed in Firefox 41](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1177463) with the following reasoning:

> It didn't get any UX review and not everyone was in agreement about the UI for it.

It is [planned to get added back again](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1178218), though.

Comment: Doesn't exist in Firefox 53 neither.

Comment: The [related bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1178218) is not closed yet, so it's also not in Firefox 54 or 55.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by popping the DevTools out into its own window (the icon just to the left of the close button). DevTools is then a separate window which can be minimized/maximized, etc.

The button to move DevTools into a separate window:
[image: Docked devtools]

The standard minimize button:
[image: DevTools in separate window with minimize]